# Does private school contract remain valid when family leaves state? Can parents be forced to cover fundraising "shortfall"?

Tags: contract-law, new-york-state, non-profit, school, new-york-city

Family signed combined tuition and "fundraising obligations" contract with a private school in NYC, in September, and moved out of state the following summer.  The school's position is that the agreement the family signed clearly listed a breakdown of quasi-charges, totaling $430 , and any shortfall of the fundraising targets for each student must be paid directly to the school.  The school is set up as a non-profit.

1. Is the small claim filed by the school still valid despite the move out of state?
2. Is it okay for a school to require check or cash payments to cover the "shortfall"?  If not, can you help me find a statute or regulation to back that up?

Comment: Following summer? They moved after the school year was over?

Comment: @damila - yes.    If it had been a year later it would be something like "a year after the summer following the relevant school year" or something like that.  Here in NY we have a huge backlog of small claims cases.

Comment: Thanks. It was rhetorical- pointing out that they did not leave during  the school year. And giving an opportunity to clarify that.  So on what rationale would you think the family does not owe the full amount?

Comment: @Damila - I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes. Yes

Contracts don’t become invalid just because one or the other of the parties relocates.

If you agreed in a contract to pay $450 then you are obliged to pay $450.